# Keycloak Token for Azure IDP user

Tags: azure, keycloak, single-sign-on, single-page-application, openid

I have linked Azure AD as an IDP in Keycloak. I am able to route to the Azure Login page and get back to keycloak redirect uri after successful login. A copy of the user is also being created in Keycloak linked to an external IDP.

Now I am able to get the Azure tokens with a combination of `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` and `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token` requests.

But I have roles and groups configured in Keycloak and want to map them to users (already figured this out by using predefined mappers) and generate a token for an external user that is coming from Azure. I can see the following token getting generated in the browser through the "authorization_code" flow. [image][image]

I am not able to get the source of the keycloak authentication code. How's it getting generated!!. Is there any other way to get the token!!.

I am trying to replicate the flow via Postman and get a Keycloak token, but I am not able to make it work as of now. If anyone faces similar issues or can provide some suggestions, that would be great. Thanks in Advance